# Mysql returns zero rows if second table has no matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT
    a.user_id AS user_id,
    a.user_name AS user_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.course_id SEPARATOR ',') AS course_ids
FROM
    user_courses b JOIN user a ON b.user_id_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY
    a.user_id;
```

I want it to return all users and their courses, I also want it to return a row for users with no courses. However the result only contains users who have at least one course. How can I get ot to return all users even if they have no courses in the `user_courses` table?

Comment: `left join` on `users`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `left join` (and to put `user` first):

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(uc.course_id SEPARATOR ',') AS course_ids
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     user_courses uc 
     ON u.user_id_id = uc.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

Notice that the query is easier to understand when you use abbreviations for table aliases instead of meaningless letters such as `a` and `b`.